# Pandas dataframe vectorizing/filtering: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have two dataframes with NHL hockey stats. One contains every game played by every team for the last ten years, and the other is where I want to fill it up with calculated values. Simply put, I want to take a metric from a team's first five games, sum it, and put that into the other df. I've trimmed my dfs below to exclude other stats and will only look at one stat.

df_all contains all of the games:

```
>>> df_all
        season      gameId playerTeam opposingTeam  gameDate  xGoalsFor  xGoalsAgainst
1         2008  2008020001        NYR          T.B  20081004      2.287          2.689
6         2008  2008020003        NYR          T.B  20081005      1.793          0.916
11        2008  2008020010        NYR          CHI  20081010      1.938          2.762
16        2008  2008020019        NYR          PHI  20081011      3.030          3.020
21        2008  2008020034        NYR          N.J  20081013      1.562          3.454
...        ...         ...        ...          ...       ...        ...            ...
142576    2015  2015030185        L.A          S.J  20160422      2.927          2.042
142581    2017  2017030171        L.A          VGK  20180411      1.275          2.279
142586    2017  2017030172        L.A          VGK  20180413      1.907          4.642
142591    2017  2017030173        L.A          VGK  20180415      2.452          3.159
142596    2017  2017030174        L.A          VGK  20180417      2.427          1.818
```

df_sum_all will contain the calculated stats, for now it has a bunch of empty columns:

```
>>> df_sum_all
     season team  xg5  xg10  xg15  xg20
0      2008  NYR    0     0     0     0
1      2009  NYR    0     0     0     0
2      2010  NYR    0     0     0     0
3      2011  NYR    0     0     0     0
4      2012  NYR    0     0     0     0
..      ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
327    2014  L.A    0     0     0     0
328    2015  L.A    0     0     0     0
329    2016  L.A    0     0     0     0
330    2017  L.A    0     0     0     0
331    2018  L.A    0     0     0     0
```

Here's my function for calculating the ratio of xGoalsFor and xGoalsAgainst.

```
def calcRatio(statfor, statagainst, games, season, team, statsdf):
    tempFor = float(statsdf[(statsdf.playerTeam == team) & (statsdf.season == season)].nsmallest(games, 'gameDate').eval(statfor).sum())
    tempAgainst = float(statsdf[(statsdf.playerTeam == team) & (statsdf.season == season)].nsmallest(games, 'gameDate').eval(statagainst).sum())
    tempRatio = tempFor / tempAgainst
    return tempRatio
```

I believe it's logical enough. I input the stat I want to make a ratio from, how many games to sum, the season and team to match on, and then where to get the stats from. I've tested these functions separately and know that I can filter just fine, and sum the stats, and so forth. Here's an example of a standalone implementation of the tempFor calculation:

```
>>> statsdf = df_all
>>> team = 'TOR'
>>> season = 2015
>>> games = 3
>>> tempFor = float(statsdf[(statsdf.playerTeam == team) & (statsdf.season == season)].nsmallest(games, 'gameDate').eval(statfor).sum())
>>> print(tempFor)
8.618
```

See? It returns a value. However I can't do the same across the whole dataframe. What am I missing? I thought the way this works is essentially for every row, it sets the 'xg5' column to the output of the calcRatio function, which uses that row's 'season' and 'team' to filter on df_all.

```
>>> df_sum_all['xg5'] = calcRatio('xGoalsFor','xGoalsAgainst',5,df_sum_all['season'], df_sum_all['team'], df_all)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in calcRatio
  File "/home/sebastian/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 1142, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled " "Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Cheers, thanks for any help!

Update: I used iterrows() and it worked fine, so I must just not understand vectorization very well. It's the same function, though - why does it work in one fashion, but not another?

```
>>> emptyseries = []
>>> for index, row in df_sum_all.iterrows():
...     emptyseries.append(calcRatio('xGoalsFor','xGoalsAgainst',5,row['season'],row['team'], df_all))
... 
>>> df_sum_all['xg5'] = emptyseries
__main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>>> df_sum_all
     season team       xg5  xg10  xg15  xg20
0      2008  NYR  0.826260     0     0     0
1      2009  NYR  1.288390     0     0     0
2      2010  NYR  0.915942     0     0     0
3      2011  NYR  0.730498     0     0     0
4      2012  NYR  0.980744     0     0     0
..      ...  ...       ...   ...   ...   ...
327    2014  L.A  0.823998     0     0     0
328    2015  L.A  1.147412     0     0     0
329    2016  L.A  1.054947     0     0     0
330    2017  L.A  1.369005     0     0     0
331    2018  L.A  0.721411     0     0     0

[332 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: For the love of god, use `itertuples` instead of `iterrows`! See the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) for some of the strange behaviour of `iterrows`. The performance is also far worse, we're talking 1000 times slower than `itertuples` on extremely basic tasks.

Comment: Also, can you provide an easier way to access the test data? Copy-pasting and messing with DataFrame output you shared would be tedious. Considering the nature of the calculations, a larger amount of test data might be necessary. In fact, I feel like the format of the data is going to have a big impact on this question. The good news is it seems relatively simple :)

Comment: Yes, I realize iterrows sucks; but at least it did work, so it confirmed my function is fine. I have to transform the data quite a bit from my input files, it's not really easy to share it.

Comment: Question on the data: Does every game appear twice, once for each team?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is ok, because I need to look at it from each team's perspective, and the alternative is to only have games appear once, but then pick through playerTeam/opposingTeam and find the first 5/10/15/etc instances among both, which is a bit more than I was planning on.

Comment: Yeah I agree that having each match appear twice makes sense. I don't know if there is much I can do to help though :/

Comment: No problem; thank you anyway :) I don't think I have a good way of avoiding this issue, without massive refactoring of the dataframes in question to somehow join them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

```
tempFor = float(statsdf[(statsdf.playerTeam == team) & (statsdf.season == season)].nsmallest(games, 'gameDate').eval(statfor).sum())
tempAgainst = float(statsdf[(statsdf.playerTeam == team) & (statsdf.season == season)].nsmallest(games, 'gameDate').eval(statagainst).sum())
```

The input for variables:

```
team: df_sum_all['team']
season: df_sum_all['season']
statsdf: df_all
```

So in the code, **(statsdf.playerTeam == team)**, it will compare between series from **df_sum_all** and from **df_all**.
If these two are not identically labeled, you will see the above error.

Comment: Thanks - I did figure that is why it's happening. Then my question is how do I avoid it? I want to run my function across the whole dataframe, vectorization makes it very fast, but I need to use multiple dataframes and thus comparing them means they are not identically labeled. I don't think I can convert them to str/int within the function, because when running it on the whole array it takes the whole column as input, not just one value at a time. So running it with .apply seems to be the fastest I can get it.

Comment: @Sebastian Two dataframes can still be identically labeled if you set the same index for them. But that requires them to have the same length. If they are not of the same length, try to join them together and filtering out some unnecessary rows and then do vectorization.

Comment: Unfortunately joining them together isn't really easy, since they contain vastly different data. I'm doing alright with df.apply. Thanks for your help!